# Why react native app keeps asking for main.js which was deleted?

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native (0.58.5) by coding a very simple chat app. There is one module `Chat.js` under `components`. But an error keeps asking for a missing module named `Main.js` under `components`. The module `Main.js` was deleted before I start 'react-native run-android`. And the error is the same even if I put the`Main.js`back under`components`. Here is the error:

```
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2019:03:12:59 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./components/Main` from `C:\D\code\js\emps_app\App.js`: The module `./components/Main` could not be found from `C:\D\code\js\emps_app\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `C:\D\code\js\emps_app\components\Main(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `C:\D\code\js\emps_app\components\Main\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:273:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:391:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:388:18)
    at C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:261:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

Here is the `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chat from "./components/Chat";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Chat />;
  }
}
```

There is no reference to `Main.js` at all above. Is the `Main.js` reserved module in `React Native`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for `index.android.bundle` and delete  from your android folder.

kill all instance of metro bundler.

In cmd or powershell of your project's android folder run `gradlew clean`

hit `react-native run-android`